# How to access a global variable across sub directories within a kernel space?

Tags: c, linux

Is there a way to have a global variable defined in a linux kernel module available across sub directories?Using the EXPORT_SYMBOL  makes it available across the current directory. I've tried defining it in a header file and including the header file in the sub directory using "../name_header.h" but it doesn't seem to recognize the variable.
In specific, I have one variable in the c file - vport.c (of openvswitch ), I want to access this variable inside a sub directory.

Comment: Can you paste your code and also the error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

`EXPORT_SYMBOL` makes a symbol available to dynamic linked code (kernel modules), but I don't think that this is what you are trying to achieve.

In order to access a variable from a different compile unit add an `extern` deceleration in the c file you are trying to access that variable. Or better, use a common header file and put the extern deceleration into that file. It typically does not matter whether that compile unit (e.g. c file) is in a different directory or sub directory.

Comment: I tried doing that as well - I tried using the header file and I  even tried placing in the  ovs/include directory(where all global headers are defined) and in the parent directory but it doesn't seem to recognize the variable